# Yii 2 Separate User Instance in Module

Tags: php, yii2

I have two different user table(editors and users) in database. User table as you know and the Editor table is just using in module.

I use [this way](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/80/add-information-to-yii-app-user-by-extending-cwebuser-better-version) to separating user instances from between module and main application in Yii 1.1.

But I can't find a way in yii 2. I try extend yii\web\User and I change user class in module but same results. If I login in module, same User instance is accessible from out of module and anywhere.

My module init like this:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    \Yii::$app->set('user', [
        'class' => 'app\modules\yonetim\components\yonetimUser',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Editor',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl' => ['yonetim/default/login'],
    ]);
}
```

Also I try this way; in config.php

```
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'editor' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Editor',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
],
```

But this time I don't use authorization roles(like @)

How can I use different User instance in my module ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found another way for different login instance. Yii2 uses session id param for authentication. So we need to change it.

Change your modules\module_name\module_name.php file to looks like this:

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Yii::$app->set('user', [
        'class' => 'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Editor',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'loginUrl' => ['yonetim/default/login'],
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => 'editor', 'httpOnly' => true],
        'idParam' => 'editor_id', //this is important !
    ]);
}
```

idParam value defined in yii\web\User as default:  $idParam = '__id'; 
So if we change this value, app and module use different user instances.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me from several hours of pain

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested this, but you may find something like `switchIdentity()` works, so in your module use this;

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $editor = new app\models\Editor
    $user = Yii::$app->user;
    $user->switchIdentity($editor);

}
```

Comment: When I use switchIdentity() function, Yii works like automatically logged in. Create a new Editor instance but same User interface. In yii docs says: "This method is mainly called by login(), logout() and loginByCookie() when the current user needs to be associated with the corresponding identity information."

Answer (score 0):

You can set different session names for your application:

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'application-session-name',
    ],
],
```

And for the module:

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'module-session-name',
    ],
],
```